# я создаю 2д игру Unity вид сверху и у меня случился баг : персонаж бесконечно поворачивается как это исправить? вот код:

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, move

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moving : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    private float moveInput;
    public Joystick joystick;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool facingRight = true;
    public bool moveright;
    public bool moveleft;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.x);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (move < 0 && facingRight)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (move > 0 && !facingRight) ;
        {
            flip();

        }
        void flip()
        {
            facingRight = !facingRight;
            transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(move > 0 && !facingRight) ;` ???

Comment: Что написали, то и делает этот скрипт. А что хотели - непонятно. Поэтому стирайте код и переписывайте. Научитесь отлаживать код, выполняйте пошагово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a flip method right in the Update method, and you want to trigger when the character walks left or right. Take the Flip method out of Update.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).